# pythonにおけるGUIについて

Tags: python, gui

GUIについて勉強中なのですが、なぜうまくできないかわからないため、どなたかご教授お願い致します。pythonにてpylinacをインストールして

```
from pylinac.py_gui import gui
gui()
```

と入力し実行できるGUIについて、ソースコードを以下のサイトから入手しました。

https://github.com/jrkerns/pylinac/blob/master/pylinac/py_gui.py

spyderにコードを入力すると同様のことが可能と思ったのですが画像のように

```
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

とエラーが発生して実行できません。

どのあたりを修正すればうまく実行できるのでしょうか？

[image]

Comment: この場合、`pylinac` モジュールから import しますので、`from pylinac import picketfence, ...` に書き直してみる(`.` を `pylinac` に変更)と良いかもしれません。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいた通り．をpylinacに変更してみました。Errorはでなくなったのですが、GUIは表示されません。　　　　　　　　`def gui():

    def on_exit():
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            root.quit()

    root = Tk()
    root.title('Pylinac GUI ' + __version__)
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_exit)
    app = PylinacGUI(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
    del root`　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 の`root quit()`   へ'''un defined name root''' と表示されるのでこれが原因かもしれません。またお気づきの点がございましたらご指摘いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 今気が付いたのですが、この `py_gui.py` には `gui()` 関数を呼び出すコードがありません。なので GUI が表示されないのはその通りかと。

Comment: 無知で申し訳ないのですが、`from pylinac.py_gui import gui　gui()`　を入力して出てくる`pylinac GUI2.4.0`というものの中味が`py_gui.py`で同じもの。前者はpylinacのパッケージに入っていて呼び出すためのものと思っていたのですが違うということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、`py_gui.py` は `pylinac` の一部でしかありません。つまり、`py_gui.py` の中身は関数とメソッドの定義しか書かれていませんので、コピーしただけでは `gui()` 関数が実行される事はありません。`untitled14.py` の最後に `if __name__ == '__main__':` という行と、その次に `gui()` という行を追加して実行する必要があります。

Comment: できました！！わかりやすい説明と夜遅くまでご対応いただきありがとうございました。また是非ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まとめますと、`from . import picketfence`を`from pylinac import picketfence`
に変更。最終行へ`if __name__ == '__main__':`と次の行へ`gui()`を追加で実行可能のようです。
ご協力いただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

gui()の実行後、GUIの画面は立ち上がりましたか？

```
~ $ python                                                               
Python 3.8.5 (default, Oct  3 2020, 10:39:10) 
>>> from pylinac.py_gui import gui
>>> gui()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: はい、貼っていただいている画像の同じ画面が立ち上がりました。
なのでソースコードを入れても同様に立ち上がると思ったのですが。